# Android activity re-created each time

Tags: android, android-activity, state, lifecycle

I have an Activity that has many fields (class fields/members). I want to set these fields by calling other activities (with startActivityForResult) but the field values are not kept. It looks like each time I return from another activity to my original one, a new instance is created and the fields are re-initialised (the onCreate() method is called each time I return from another activity, also onDestroy() is called on the original one each time I load another activity with startActivityForResult; I am never calling finish()). I hope I explained my problem well.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks,
Silviu

Comment: I solved my problem by overriding onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState and saving/restoring all my data. But still I don't think this is the answer to my issue above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your fields have unique id's as Android uses these id's to retain the field values when it redraws the activity.

Comment: I was talking about class fields/members. I don't understand why the Activity class I am using gets re-instantiated (and all its class members are reset to their declarations).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the Android Manifest for the Activity where you have the startActivityForResult code?

If so remove that launchMode as it as some known issues with startActivityForResult.

Comment: No, I don't have that set for any activity in my AndroidManifest.